# Webex unable to resize smaller, overlap. Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, webex

I have downloaded webex for ubuntu 21.10. when I open the meeting window, it overlaps and I can not see the bottom of the window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITpRu.png)

I have tried to resize it but it is the smallest size already. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my problem is when I open the webex video call, the window is too long and wide, and the bottom is not showing